# Python tuple in wanted format

Tags: python, arrays, string, tuples

I have a prime factorization program:

```
import sys
import math

def prime_factorize(n):
    factors = []
    number = math.fabs(n)

    while number > 1:
        factor = get_next_prime_factor(number)
        factors.append(factor)
        number /= factor

    if n < -1:
        factors[0] = -factors[0]

    return tuple(factors)

def get_next_prime_factor(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2

    for x in range(3, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1), 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return x

    return int(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: %s <integer>" % sys.argv[0])
        exit()

    try:
        number = int(sys.argv[1])
    except ValueError:
        print("'%s' nie jest liczba calkowita!" % sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print ("%d =" %number, *prime_factorize(number), sep='*')
```

The program returns for 123456:

```
123456 =*2*2*2*2*2*2*3*643
```

And I wanted to get output in format:

```
123456 = 2^6*3*643
```

The best solution is to convert tuple to string? How to get this output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
...
    else:
        tup = prime_factorize(number)
        print("{} = {}".format(number, "*".join("{}^{}".format(x, tup.count(x)) if tup.count(x) > 1 else str(x) for x in sorted(set(tup)))))
```

Output:

```
123456 = 2^6*3*643
```